# Create a function with 'trapz' tool? and apply lappy?

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to calculate the 'trapezoidal AUC(area under the curve)' by using the 'trapz' tool from 'caTools'. It is very simple to calculate one variable's AUC when using trapz like this:

```
tAUC <- trapz(df1$time, df1$CAT.19)
tAUC
```

Now, I want to create a function with this and eventually 'lapply' it to do batch calculation, but having trouble making this into a function.
I have tried like:

```
t_func <- function(x){
  trapz(df1$time, df1$x)
}
```

but having error that says "non-conformable arguments"
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you so much.
[my df1 looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjU42.png)

Answer (score 0):

An image is not helpful way to share data. I have created a fake dataset to reproduce the dataset that you have.

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 120, 15), CAT.01 = rnorm(9), CAT.02 = rnorm(9))

tAUC <- sapply(df1[-1], function(x) caTools::trapz(df1$time, x))
tAUC

#  CAT.01   CAT.02 
#27.23374 39.27199
```

If you need a list you may use `lapply` instead of `sapply`.

Comment: Yes, I should have shared my data not in an image. This resolved my issue. Thank you so much.